# AJAX requests from a React component

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am having a react component that looks something like this. It internally uses highcharts-react to render a chart by fetching a data from an API by supplying the API some of its state properties.

```
export default class CandlestickChart extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            apiParam1: this.props.propData.param1,
            apiParam2: this.props.propData.param2,
            chartConfig: this.getChartConfig(this.props.apiParam1),
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.renderChart();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='col-lg-6'>
                <div className='well'>
                    <ReactHighStock config={this.state.chartConfig} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    renderChart() {
        var that = this;
        NanoAjax.ajax({
            url: 'myApi.com?param1=' + this.state.apiParam1 + '&param2=' + this.state.apiParam2;
        }, function (statusCode, responseText) {
            //transform the data a bit

            var chartConfig = that.getChartConfig(that.state.apiParam1);
            chartConfig.series[0].data = chartData;

            that.setState({
                chartConfig: chartConfig
            })
        });
    }

    getChartConfig(param1) {
        // returns HighCharts chartConfig object based on apiParam1
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine as long as the component is static, i.e., once the params are set during initial render, the parent control will never update it. Also, this approach is same as given in here : https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/

However, my requirement is that, the parent control can update the props `param1` and `param2` of this control, causing it to make a fresh ajax call with these values and re-render the chart with new data.

How to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solutions renders the chart only when the component has been mounted

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.renderChart();
}
```

While the requirement is to rerender the chart once `param1` and `param2` change. For that we could use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops), where you'll compare values and act accordingly

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  let shouldRerenderChart = false;

  shouldRerenderChart = shouldRerenderChart || this.props.propData.param1 !== nextProps.propData.param1;

  shouldRerenderChart = shouldRerenderChart || this.props.propData.param2 !== nextProps.propData.param2;

  if (shouldRerenderChart) { 
    this.renderChart();
  }
}
```

Also, keep your componentDidMount function, because

> React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during mounting.

---

As an alternative you could use [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) with a similar approach.

Comment: But can I call `renderChart` from `componentWillReceiveProps` since generally functions containing `will` don't allow `setState` to be called from their call stack?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is exactly where you'd like to call setState and it won't trigger double rerender, see this is from the official docs: componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in this method.

Comment: got it, trying it now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the solution :)